# Pull random image from entries marked with a certain category

Tags: entries, categories, random

I am trying to pull an image from services marked with a category of left. I would only like to display one image. I would also like to randomize the image if possible from all the images marked left.

```
{# RANDOM IMAGE FROM SERVICES - LEFT #}
<div class="grid-item">
    {% for homepage in craft.entries.section('services').limit('1').relatedTo(left).find() %}
        <div class="image-wrapper overlay-fade-in">

            <img src="{{ homepage.homepageImage.first().getUrl }}" alt="{{ homepage.title }}"/>

            <div class="image-overlay-content">

                <h2>{{ homepage.title }}</h2>
                <p>{{ homepage.description }}</p>
                <a href="services.html" class="button">View Rental Pricing</a>

            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to the Craft community @bjyama

```
{# Step one: pick a random service #}
{% set randomService = craft.entries.section('services').relatedTo(left).order('RAND()').first() %}

{# Step two: pick a random image from the above service #}
{% set randomServiceImage = service.homepageImage.order('RAND()').first() %}

{% if randomServiceImage %}
    <img src="{{ randomServiceImage.getUrl('imageTransformName') }}" alt="">
{% endif %}
```

For more info, have a look here: https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/craft.entries#order

Let us know how you get on :)

Comment: Fair enough, cheers Mats!

Comment: Yeah, the `for` loops weren't neccessary/would fail as you're using `first()` :) Could do with a conditional testing the `randomService` variable, but otherwise this looks legit – assuming `left` is a CategoryModel instance, of course :)

Comment: I'm beginning to understand the code above. However, when you say "assuming left is a CategoryModel instance" what do you mean?

I have created a Category called homepageView and then created two categories in it called right and left. 

I then created a category field called homepageImageLayout and added it to my services channel. I selected left in one of the entries.

Comment: @bjyama `.relatedTo(left)` will only work if the variable `left` is actually set to a category (i.e. an instance of [CategoryModel](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/categorymodel)). By itself, using `left` will only throw an error (undefined variable). From your description, I'm don't really understand how you structured this so I'm unable to give you a good example, but you'll need something like `{% set left = craft.categories.group('yourCategoryGroupHandle').slug('left').first() %}` somewhere in your template (before the `{% set randomService...` part).